# In Access 2010 how would I find all of the null fields in my table and replace them with user supplied data?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access 2010 database that is going to import data from an excel sheet and append that data to the proper table. The issue I am having is that once imported, the data will not have the customer ID attached to it so the cust_ID field in the table will be null. What I need is a macro that will ask the user who the customer is for each import and then find that customer's ID and put that value into all of the null fields. I have made a lot of different attempts at this (mostly though the macro builder I don't even know where to start with the VBA for this) none of which have shown any results. I think my latest one is close but for some reason it isn't running after the import. I have an "After Insert" macro, and the idea was that it would prompt the user for [Customer Name]
look-up the custID from TBL_Customers then insert that into each of the null fields. Unfortunately after I import my data nothing happens and I'm really not sure why.

```
Parameters Name: Customer Name

Look Up A Record In TBL_Customers
Where Condition =[TBL_Customers].[FLD_Customer_Name]=[Customer Name]
Alias custName

Look Up A Record In TBL_Customers
    Where Condition =[TBL_Customers].[FLD_Customer_PK_ID]=[custName]
    Alias custID

For Each Record In TBL_Contacts
Where condition =IsNull([FLD_Contact_FK_Customer_ID])

EditRecord
    SetField
        Name FLD_Contact_FK_Customer_ID
        Value =[custID]
End EditRecord
```

Another possibility I was thinking would be to have another column in the excel sheet with the customer's name and then Access would just have to look up the cust_ID based on that column. My issue there is I don't know how I would tell Access to import the customer name from the excel sheet find that customer's ID and insert that ID into the proper table, which is why I was leaning toward the first option.

As I said in the comments I've tried a lot of different things but I'm fairly new to VBA/Access and am running out of ideas to try.
Not sure which would be easier/better so any ideas/suggestions/recommendations are greatly appreciated.

Comment: This may get flagged for an opinion oriented question since your not actually asking a specific question just FYI.  You may want to actually narrow down a method that you plan on using, try it, and then let us know what worked or didn't work.  I would recommend creating everything in Excel (including the ID), transfer it to Access with the ID, and work from a local table though.

Comment: I like the 2nd option, but instead of another spreadsheet, you can put your lookup table in the Access db.  Once you build it out, there will be less work for everyone involved.  Just make sure that the incoming Excel files are spelling the customer names as you expect and that the lookup table stays up to date.

Comment: Also, it would help us if you were to edit your question and add a few things: example data, example table structure, the VBA you've already tried, etc.  That lets us see your skill level and shows that you're not just "give me teh codez"

Comment: Thanks I've tried a lot of different things none of which have come up with any results. I have some experience with SQL and a little Access but mostly I'm learning as I go. I could possibly use @TKEyi60 idea but I don't think it would be a good fix long term once we have more and more customers in the database it would get too hard to keep track of the customer ID's in excel. I'll add some edits up top of things I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample of something that might get you going in the right direction.  In my case I had a similar situation, importing from excel, but often one piece of data was missing.  What I did was had the "users" save the excel docs into subfolders with the customer id's as part of the folder names.  Using the Scripting library you can recurse through the subfolders, and I use a custom FindCustomerID function to parse the ID you are looking for from the path name.  Once the import happens, the customer id can be added in.

```
Function ImportBlah(importDir As String, tbl As String)

Dim importPath As String
Dim fs As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fo, x AS Folder
Dim fi AS File
Dim custID As String

Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 

With fs
    Set fo = .GetFolder(importDir)
    For Each x In fo.SubFolders
        For Each fi In x.Files
            If Not (fi.Attributes Mod 8 >= 4) Then 'If not a system file
                DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, "import_specs", tbl, fi, True
                custID = FindCustomerID(x.Path)
                CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE " & tbl & " SET FileName = '" _ 
                   & fi.ParentFolder.name & "\" & fi.name & "' WHERE FileName IS NULL", _ 
                   dbFailOnError 'Add filename to Filename column
                CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE " & tbl & " SET custID = '" & _ 
                   custID & "' WHERE custID IS NULL", dbFailOnError 'Add custID to custID column
                .MoveFile fi, x & "\Imported\"
            End If
        Next
    Next
End With    
End Function
```

This code requires the reference to the Microsoft Scripting Runtime be enabled.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't say how to do this with Access macros, but it isn't too hard to do in VBA.

I'd write the macro in excel - import the activex data objects 2.8 library reference.

Start by declaring the connection object - this works for a MySQL server we have set up, you can use the JET driver if you're just connecting over a local network.

```
Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
cnn.CursorLocation = adUseServer
cnn.Open "Driver={MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver};Server=myserver;database=my_db;uid=user;pwd=P@ssword"
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
```

When you have the customer name (Get the name from the user, maybe by an inputbox) ping the DB to retrieve the id and save it.

```
rst.open "Select id from customers where customername = '"  & userSubmittedName & "'", 
cnn,adopenforwardonly,adlockbatchoptimistic

dim customerID as integer
customerID = rst.fields("id").Value
```

Then it's just a matter of inputting the data.  Access has the DoCmd.RunSQL command, but in Excel you'd use ADO recordsets.  It works like this -

```
rst.open "Select * from Orders",cnn,adopenforwardonly,adlockbatchoptimistic
Fo r x = 2 to rowCount 'Once you have the number of rows you're inputting saved obviously
 rst.addnew
 rst.fields("ID") = customerID
 rst.fields("OrderAmount") = range("A" & x).value
 rst.fields("SaleAmount") = range("B" & x).value
 ....
 rst.update
next x
```